# Functional programming with Associations

Tags: associations, time-series

Suppose I have an association where keys are dates, and values are returns of some portfolio, and I want to convert the returns to cumulative returns. Now, this can be done as follows:

```
Association[
    Module[ {porfolio = KeySort[port]},
        MapThread[Rule, {Keys[porfolio], Exp[FoldList[Plus, Values[portfolio]]]}]
    ]
]
```

But this seems clunky. Is there some more elegant way of achieving the aim?

Comment: Can you post a short example of `port`?

Comment: @Stitch Sure, here is a not-so-short example: https://www.dropbox.com/s/og07v3l8e020c3w/egport.m?dl=0

Comment: Does anyone know why `Accumulate[ <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3|> ]` doesn't work?  I thought this kind of thing was missing from version 10 simply because there wasn't time to add it, but it still doesn't work in version 11.1.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Would that no be because the internal ordering of the association has nothing to do a priori with what you type in, and thus it is not clear what order you are accumulating in? Just a thought...

Comment: @Mr. Wizard, to make Igor's thought explicit: would you expect `Accumulate[ <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3|>]` and `Accumulate[<|"a" -> 1, "c" -> 3, "b" -> 2|>]` to give the same results, or not?

Comment: @J.M. No I would not; `KeySort` is there if needed.  If `Association` is too vague what about `Dataset`?

Comment: @Mr. Wizard, on a `Dataset[]` *without* named rows, I can see `Accumulate[]` working on it. Otherwise...

Answer (score 7):

Best I can tell you really just want [`AssociationThread`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AssociationThread.html). It circumvents the `Association` and the `MapThread`.

```
p = AssociationThread[Range[100], Range[100]];
AssociationThread[Keys@p, N@Exp[FoldList[Plus, Values[p]]]]
```

That does what you were doing before in a few fewer calls. Also note that `Associations` support lots of functional programming stuff. `KeyMap` and `Map` exist of course and `KeyValueMap` is there too.

If you're wondering why `FoldList` doesn't do this natively consider that `Fold` and`FoldList` are supposed to be direct counter-parts. `FoldList` *could* return an `Association` with the keys realigned, but that wouldn't make sense with `Fold`. So there's no way to make an intuitive, compatible definition across both of them. And so best to one for neither of them. With `AssociationThread` rebuilding your association is trivial anyway, so I think they didn't really see the need either.

Comment: There is a problem with this (which I pointed out in one of my comments to another answer) is that the ordering of keys in an association is (intentionally) non-deterministic, so one pretty much has to do a KeySort before this has any semantic content... Still, I had no idea `AssociationThread` existed!

Comment: @IgorRivin Yes and no. It's like a hash-map with ordering. So it can be indexed just like a list. If you want something with keys ordered according to their hash values you can check out the internal ``System`Private`HashTable``. Never figured out exactly how it works, so if you do post a Q&A type question on it for me to upvote.

Comment: I am guessing that the ordering depends on the hashing algorithm, which is not guaranteed to remain whatever it is today...

Comment: @IgorRivin Of course not. But few top-level structures (none I can currently think of) will impose an ordering on their equivalent of the hash table keys. You'll probably have to go internal if you want that.

Comment: The documentation states that `Sort` and `KeySort` can be applied to associations to produce well-ordered associations.  Furthermore, associations are documented to support numeric part indices and value updating from ordered lists.  From these assertions, we must conclude that association element order is being actively preserved independently of the key representation (e.g. like Java's _LinkedHashMap_).  Still, it would be nice if the documentation explicitly stated that association maintain their order rather than just these implicit statements.

Comment: Also, the distinction between "regular" associations and explicitly unordered associations is very suggestive, e.g. ``Outer[#2 @#@{"b" -> 1, "a" -> 2} &, {Association, Data`UnorderedAssociation}, {# &, InputForm, Internal`AssociationNodes}] // Grid``.

Comment: @WReach oh I totally misunderstood what Igor was after. I must have assumed it was known that they'd stay ordered. You mention the *LinkedHashMap* in Java. In python there's the *OrderedDict* equivalent.

Comment: @WReach I'm guessing ``Data`UnorderedAssociation`` exists to get you back to constant indexing time rather than simply log2(n).

Answer (score 6):

The shortest (and faster) way is to use [`Accumulate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Accumulate.html) with pre-computed sorted [`Association`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association.html):

```
eg = <|"2012-08-29" -> -0.2, "2012-08-30" -> 0.2, 
   "2012-08-31" -> -0.05, "2012-09-04" -> 0.05, "2012-09-05" -> -0.5, 
   "2012-09-01" -> -0.2, "2012-09-07" -> -0.3, "2012-09-10" -> 0.9|>;
egs = KeySort@eg;
AssociationThread[Keys@egs, egs // Values // Accumulate // Exp]
```

> `<|"2012-08-29" -> 0.818731, "2012-08-30" -> 1., 
>    "2012-08-31" -> 0.951229, "2012-09-01" -> 0.778801, 
>    "2012-09-04" -> 0.818731, "2012-09-05" -> 0.496585, 
>    "2012-09-07" -> 0.367879, "2012-09-10" -> 0.904837|>`

Comment: That is a good way, though (to play devil's advocate :)) it ONLY works with Plus as the thing being accumulated...

Comment: @IgorRivin Well, you know, they say there is a function for everything in MMA :)

Answer (score 6):

These are not functional solutions, but they are fairly concise owing to the "transparency" of associations to operators like `Map` and `Exp`:

```
Module[{t = 0}, Map[t += # &, eg]] // Exp
```

or `Set`:

```
Module[{e = eg}, e[[All]] = e // Values // Accumulate // Exp; e]
```

These solutions assume that the association `eg` is already in the desired order (like the file linked in the question -- use `KeySort@eg` if necessary).

Answer (score 3):

You could write a version of `FoldList` that works on Associations:

```
foldList[f_, assoc_Association] := 
    MapThread[Rule, {Keys@assoc, FoldList[f, Values@assoc]}] // Association
```

Then you can simply do

```
Exp /@ foldList[ Plus, KeySort@port ]
```

Comment: True, but the principle is still the same, and the whole disassembling-reassembling process seems inelegant...

Comment: @Igor Absent something built in, I think one has to choose between disassembling-reassembling or for-loop-style iteration.

Comment: @Igor Aside from that issue, are you hoping for something more elegant?  I find it hard to imagine something more elegant than a `FoldList`-like solution.

Comment: I agree, but it is not obvious that something is *not* built in (Associations support some, but not all, list operations, so it seems a little underbaked, so maybe more baking had occurred while we were not looking?!)

Comment: I guess part of the point is that there is no canonical order on the keys of an association, so things like `Fold` don't a *a priori* make sense, so maybe you are right - this maybe the best one can hope for...